# How can I skip comments with specific string in grep regex command with one command that contain specific string?

Tags: unix, grep

I have file with this content:

```
path=/nfs/location/alex 
path = /nfs/location/ 
alex/nfs/location 
/nfs/location/
# /nfs/location/
#alex /nfs/location
alex # d /nfs/location
/nfs/location
```

I want to print all line where no comments # and contain path that start with /nfs/location

```
path=/nfs/location/alex 
path = /nfs/location/ 
/nfs/location/
/nfs/location
```

I wrote unix commad:

```
grep -rE ([^#.*]|^[^0-9aA-zZ]/nfs/location/ .
```

but lines with # also appear

Comment: Sorry, but your goal description does not make sense, please revise it to make clear what _exactly_ you are looking for. "all line where path starts with and don't contain #"... starts with _what_?

Comment: updated @arkascha

Comment: @Alex, why `alex/nfs/location` is missed from the result? This contradicts with your comment *path is only example of string. it is not constant.*

Comment: because string not start with /nfs/location @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @Alex, this `path = /nfs/location/` also NOT starting with `/nfs/location`, though it's in the result. Your logic is vague

Comment: you must not that path starts with number or abc. @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 0):

GNU **grep** approach:

```
grep -P '^([^#]+[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*)?/nfs/location' file
```

The output:

```
path=/nfs/location/alex 
path = /nfs/location/ 
/nfs/location/
/nfs/location
```

Comment: path is only example of string. it is not constant. @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @Alex, you should have mentioned that condition in your question

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
awk -F'[= ]+' 'index($NF,"/nfs/location")==1 && !/#/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^path|^\/nfs/' file

path=/nfs/location/alex 
path = /nfs/location/ 
/nfs/location/
/nfs/location
```